# Atomic async/await calls - is it possible to not execute first if second fails?

Tags: javascript, async-await, atomic

I'm asking on a bit of a whim as I'm no convinced this is possible to due the way time works, but was wondering if anyone had encountered a solution to this.

Would it be possible to make multiple async calls to different API endpoints that depend on each other atomic? In the sense that should one of them fail - none of them execute?

For example, if we needed to make 2 API requests, the first to POST a user and the second to make a POST using the ID returned from the first request. However, if I was unable to complete the second POST request - the user would not be created. Without this dependency I would default to using something such as `Promise.all()` however since I'm dependant on the result of the first call I don't think this would be the correct approach.

Comment: What would happen if the first request goes through but the second doesn't? Do you need to rollback whatever the first request did?

Comment: I believe so, the idea that doing API calls A and B are considered "one action" so if B failed (but was dependant on something returned from A) then the process isn't left as a "half-completed action" if that makes sense? So I suppose an endpoint or operation to rollback the previous call would be needed then? E.g. The call of making a user is fine but the call of using that ID fails so in the catch we simply call to delete the user or something...?

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be possible to make multiple async calls to different API
> endpoints that depend on eachother atomic? In the sense that should
> one of them fail - none of them execute?

Yes, through a promise rejection.

Say you need to do two async operations sequentially (one after the other). You would do:

```
doA().then(doB);
```

If `doA` throws an error it rejects the promise and does `doB` does not get called. You can then catch the error and handle it in whatever way you might need. With `async` functions you would do:

```
(async function(){
  let a = await doA();
  let b = await doB(a);
})();
```

Which again, if `doA` throws an error then `doB` call does not happen.

You can make `doA` and `doB` throw different types of error to handle them differently (if needed, like for example... doing a rollback on A if B fails).

```
class DoAError extends Error { };
class DoBError extends Error { };

async function doA(){
   //...
   //... throw new DoAError();
   //...
}

async function doB(){
   //...
   //... throw new DoBError();
   //...
}
```

And then you just handle it like this:

```
(async function(){
  try {
    let a = await doA();
    let b = await doB(a);
  } catch(e){
    if(e instanceof DoAError){ /* something wrong with DoA */ }
    else if(e instanceof DoBError){ /* something wrong with DoB */ }
    else { throw e; }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special to handle this case.  Try this:

1. Set flags to determine if each API completes,
2. Run an `endfunc()` at the end of each API-calling function,
3. Only proceed with `endcall()`'s logic if each flag is set.

Set the flags...

```
var api1 = api2 = false;
```

Define your API-calling functions...

```
apicall1() {
    // do api call
    api1 = true;
    endfunc();
}

apicall2() {
    // do another api call
    api2 = true;
    endfunc();
}
```

And finish it all off with a...

```
endfunc() {
    if(api1 !== true && api2 !== true) {
        return;
    }
    // stuff to execute only after all API calls are done
}`
```